# How can I proceed run task on API Connect(IBM Bluemix)?

Tags: ibm-cloud, apiconnect

I'm in the tutorial of Bank A.

http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSMNED_5.0.0/com.ibm.apic.toolkit.doc/tutorial_cli_api_def_working.html%23topic_qdj_dtb_gv?cp=SSMNED_5.0.0&lang=en

In API Designer(the part of IBM API Connect),I clicked the "run" button.
There is error about loading module.
How Can I fix this issue?

Then, I got the following output.

```
$ apic edit
 Express server listening on http://127.0.0.1:9000
 Unhandled rejection Error: Service manager failed to start. Please review > /home/sugai/.apiconnect/strong-pm/start.log for details.
     at ChildProcess. (/usr/lib/node_modules/apiconnect/node_modules/apiconnect-cli-pm/lib/start/pm.js:122:23)
    at ChildProcess.g (events.js:260:16)
    at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
    at Process.onexit (/usr/lib/node_modules/apiconnect/node_modules/apiconnect-cli-edit/node_modules/apim-ui/node_modules/loopback-workspace/node_modules/loopback/node_modules/continuation-local-storage/node_modules/async-listener/glue.js:188:31)
```

Reviewed the log file. There is following output.

https://gist.github.com/hokkai7go/ee0d453a60e60e1ab9109a851edae0c4

Comment: Have you tried re-running npm install from the root directory? The error log seems to indicate a module dependency is missing

Comment: When you installed apiconnect did you use the --unsafe-perm option?

Comment: What platform did you install on and were there any errors during installation? Wondering if you got a bad sqlite build...

Comment: After this comment received, I tried re-running npm install from the root directory by root user. But, this situation wasn't resolved.

Comment: I tried installation with the --unsafe-perm option, but this situation wasn't resolved.

Comment: Platform is Linux 64bit. $ uname -a
Linux <hostname> 2.6.32-573.18.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Feb 9 22:46:17 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: API Connect is supported on Node.js version 4.x.x prior to 4.2.6. Please see the document at 
https://new-console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/apiconnect/apic_003.html#apic_003  Can you please confirm that you have installed API connect on the supported version of the Node?

Comment: You may have had installation errors for installing API connect toolkit.  There is a updated Toolkit available now.  Uninstall the toolkit by following the steps:

Comment: @YutaroSugai: Have you tried uninstalling and then updating the API connect toolkit as suggested above?